# Too many nodes in tikz path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm generating tikz images from R tikzDevice library, which produces working tikz plots.

However, on some occasions, the generated path is too long (more than 100 nodes).
Tikz then complains: `"Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?"`

I've tracked the issue to `tikz.code.tex` around line 2570

```
\def\tikz@skip#1{\tikz@scan@next@command#1}%
\def\tikz@expand{%
  \advance\tikz@expandcount by -1%
  \ifnum\tikz@expandcount<0\relax%
    \tikzerror{Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?}%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@finish%
  \else%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand
  \fi%
  \pgfutil@next}%

\def\tikz@@expand{%
  \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\pgf@let@token}%
```

The counter `expandcount` is implicitly set to 100.

```
\def\tikz@@command@path{%
  ...
  \tikz@expandcount=100\relax%
  ...
}%
```

Is there any way of changing the counter value to something higher (I'm not that TeX-savvy)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following lines to your preamble, somewhere after loading `tikz` (if in doubt, add the lines before `\begin{document}`).

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\tikz@@command@path{\tikz@expandcount=100\relax}{\tikz@expandcount=1000\relax}{}{}% replace 1000 by whatever number suffices
\makeatother
```